# Tag synonym request: [postgresql] ↔ [postgres]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[postgresql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) feels more proper, but [postgres](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres) has been more popular.  They should be synonymized, though I don't know which one should be canonical.

Comment: [Well, according to SO, postgresql is the master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql).

Comment: When this is decided, just propose the synonym and I'll finalize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tags have now been synonymized, with [postgresql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) as the master.

Answer (score 7):

Upvote this if you prefer master [postgresql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) ← synonym [postgres](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres).

Answer (score 1):

Upvote this if you prefer master [postgres](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres) ← synonym [postgresql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql).

Comment: I think that postgres is going to be typed first. it should show up first to.

Comment: @Malachi It shouldn't matter that one is a prefix of the other. Once they are synonymized, autocomplete would only suggest the master.

Comment: @Malachi: It just depends on which is more accurate, which seems to be postgresql.

Comment: on code review the postgresql tag doesn't even have a wiki on it yet.

Comment: @Malachi But if we decide that we prefer [tag:postgresql], it's a simple cut-and-paste job to fix that.

Comment: now I can't un up vote this answer....itchy trigger fingers anyway.